# how to add expire headers for dropbox files?

Tags: header, dropbox

how can i add expire headers for my files (etc: images) in dropbox?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a tech support question about a web-based service, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik not at all - Dropbox isn't primarily a hosting provider.

Comment: Host your images elsewhere or you won't have expire headers.